# Why am I getting error 500 (Internal Server Error) on my ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter-3

the problem begins when I try to use my data to the server. once I uncomment this line `$data_product = $this->item->addProduct($descripcion,$cost_price,$selling_price,$wprice,$stock);` I get the problem 500 Internal Server Error, but I dont know why if I have everything ok, ids,names, etc. I want to send my array to the server. how can I debug this error and fix it? I tried it to see my logs, and there are nothing..

this is the link: http://alasksoft.tk/inventory/product
login credentials: admin - admin

controller

```
public function addProduct(){
        $descripcion = $this->input->post('description');
        $cost_price =  $this->input->post('cost_price');
        $selling_price = $this->input->post('selling_price');
        $wprice = $this->input->post('wprice');
        $stock = $this->input->post('stock');
        $data_product = $this->item->addProduct($descripcion,$cost_price,$selling_price,$wprice,$stock);
        $data = array(
            'description' => $descripcion,
            'cost_price' => $cost_price,
            'selling_price' => $selling_price,
            'wprice' => $wprice,
            'stock' => $stock
        );
        $this->json($data_product);
    }
```

model

```
public function addProduct($descripcion,$cost_price,$selling_price,$wprice,$stock){
        $data = array(
            'descripcion' => $descripcion,
            'precio_compra' => $cost_price,
            'precio_venta' => $selling_price,
            'precio_mayoreo' => $wprice,
            'existencia' => $stock
        );

        $query = $this->db->insert('storelte_articulos',$data);
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

ajax

```
$('#add').on('click',function(){
        $("#description").mask("(999) 999-9999");
        $("#new_product").validate();
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            message: function(dialog) { 
                var $message = $('<div></div>');
                var pageToLoad = dialog.getData('pageToLoad');
                $message.load(pageToLoad);

                return $message;
            },
            data: {
                'pageToLoad': URL_GET_VIEW_PRODUCT
            },
            closable: false,
            buttons:[{
                id: 'btn-ok',
                cssClass: 'btn-primary',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-send',
                label: ' Save',
                action: function (e) {
                    var description = $('#description').val();
                    var cost_price = $('#cost_price').val();
                    var selling_price = $('#selling_price').val();
                    var wprice = $('#wprice').val();
                    var stock = $('#stock').val();
                    if($("#new_product").valid()){
                        $.ajax({
                            url: URL_GET_ADD_PRODUCT,
                            type: 'POST',
                            data: {description: description, cost_price: cost_price, selling_price: selling_price, wprice: wprice, stock: stock}
                        }).done(function (e) {
                            console.log(e);
                        });
                    }
                }
            },{
                id: 'btn-cancel',
                cssClass: 'btn-danger',
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                label: ' Cancel',
                action: function (e) {
                    e.close();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
```

Comment: enable error displaying or writing errors to log to see what is the actual error message

Comment: how? it's not my server I have empty the log file

Comment: Is `URL_GET_ADD_PRODUCT` a real URL ? You don't set it in a VAR

Comment: yeah , this is http://alasksoft.tk/inventory/product/addProduct

Comment: So try with `url: "http://alasksoft.tk/inventory/product/addProduct"` and let me know if it solves it

Comment: I dont set in a var , if I comment this line $data_product = $this->item->addProduct($descripcion,$cost_price,$selling_price,$wprice,$stock); works, but this line is the method where the tables are